# phpmyadmin - Cannot connect to remote AWS instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect with phpmyadmin to a database in a remote Amazon Web Services Instance. I found a blog with some info about this [Blog](http://www.danielmois.com/article/Manage_remote_databases_from_localhost_with_phpMyAdmin).

As it says, I have to add these lines in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'password';
```

But if I enter to localhost/phpmyadmin, it doesn't show any tables.
So I tried to replace "$i++;" with "$i = 1;" to make my remote server the default, but I got an error:

## 2002 - Connection timed out

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

I'm running Ubuntu 16.4 on both, the instance and my computer.
Also, I have PHP 7.0.15 on my computer and PHP 5.6.30 on the instance.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled remote database ?

Comment: you cant connect to "localhost" from a remote machine